# Equivalent T model of a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

While deriving equivalent T model of a MOSFET from its hybrid pi model,in the last step, how can we replace the portion of the circuit below node X into a resistance of value \$\frac{1}{g_m}\$ ?

[image]

[Click to get the Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wNzJz4Sj8Q)

Comment: Try read here http://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/9780199339136/student/app/app_d page 3 D.3 Source-Absorption Theorem. "We can replace this controlled source by a resistance as long as this resistance draws an equal
current as the source. Thus the value of the resistance is vgs/gm*vgs = 1/gm." Or here https://paginas.fe.up.pt/~fff/eBook/MDA/Met_tran_cir.html

Comment: @G36 Yes, I was thinking about that...But what about the dangling wires from the source in the third figure.....?Do we not need to worry about that?

Comment: You can add this dangling wires if you like to the source as it was in the third figure. But these wires don't change anything.

Comment: @G36 Right only the current source is modified. Rest remains the same.....Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Current proportional to a voltage is resistance:
R = V/I = gm*Vgs

Comment: Hmm but what about the dangling wires from the source of figure 3....Some current will be flowing through those... Dont we need to consider that?

Comment: The voltage across the resistor sets the current.  Whatever is connected to the source will have to have a current set by that voltage and resistance.